# Is there a way to check query bind values in jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

We have a problem with queries that contain `IN` conditions with many bind params, because they have many variations and quickly overflow the query cache.

I want to check in condition clause of my sql statement and throw an exception, if there more than 30 bind values specified for in clause.

Can I use `VisitListener` for that?

I can use org.jooq.VisitContext#clause to find `in` or `not in` condition, but I can’t check `org.jooq.impl.InCondition#values` size without reflection.

Now I'm forced to do something like this:

```
public class MyVisitListener extends DefaultVisitListener {
    @Override
    public void visitStart(VisitContext context) {
        if (context.clause() == Clause.CONDITION_IN || context.clause() == Clause.CONDITION_NOT_IN) {
            try {
                Field field = context.queryPart().getClass().getDeclaredField("values");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object value = field.get(context.queryPart());
                if (((Object[]) value).length > 30) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("More than 30 bind values specified!");
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                //throw new UnknownException("Can`t check size of field 'values' in " + context.queryPart().getClass().getName(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more convenient way (jOOQ 3.10.8 pro)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came here to suggest `IN` list padding ([as Petr did very nicely, in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300134/521799)). Other than that, the proper `VisitListener` solution would be to listen to the `CONDITION_IN` clause, remember that information in some sort of stack, and then count all the `FIELD` clauses that come immediately afterwards, until the `CONDITION_IN` clause ends again. And keep in mind that instead of a bind value, there might also be an expression (again containing several `FIELD` clauses) in the `IN` list.

Clearly, Petr's suggestion is *much* easier.

Comment: Thank you, now I'll try this option

Comment: @АндрейДеревянко: I definitely suggest Petr's approach, which was designed precisely to solve / work around your problem! My solution might be correct, but is rather difficult to get right... Besides, you're throwing an exception at runtime, perhaps in production, rather than allowing for a select few long statements to get through in a normalised O(log (N)) complexity. As Petr explained, with your limit of 30 bind variables, you will still get more cursors than with the flag, in case of which you'd get 30 cursors only for lists up to 2^30!

Comment: Not so difficult, at least I was able to do what I wanted :)
Instead of throwing an exception, this warning will be written to the application log

Answer (score 4):

Another option, an often acceptable workaround to your problem, is enabling the [optional in-list padding in jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-in-list-padding/):

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-runtime-3.10.8.xsd">
  <inListPadding>true</inListPadding>
</settings>
```

It's not exactly what you want, but it might be exactly what you need. In short, it makes jOOQ generate `IN` conditions that are always power-of-2 long. This makes it much easier on the query cache.

Instead of this (8 queries):

```sql
-- Original
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

you'll see this (4 queries, and getting better as the length grows):

```sql
-- Padded
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: This is interesting feature, but it can`t solve problem with query plan optimization - we need to optimize 2^n query plans. 
But anyway, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 2^N because it's the other way around - instead of having to cache N queries, you'll only have to cache ~log N queries. Only 6 variations of a query for up to 31 bind params... And only 7 variations for up to 63 bind param... Limiting your developers at runtime (!) to only binding 30 values still seems overly artificial. That said, you know your domain the best so I'm happy you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: @lukaseder you sneaky, sneaky ninja

Comment: @PetrJaneček: I don't know how on earth my answer got accepted here, given how complicated it will be to get this `VisitListener` thing right :-)

Comment: This solution solves only the problem of query cache overflow. However, the database administrator will be forced to configure 2^N different query plans, instead of one